# Embedded Kafka Failed to Start After Spring Starter Parent Version 3.1.10

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, junit, embedded-kafka

I'm trying to run some integration tests for Kafka consumer with,

> org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka

Currently letting spring-boot-starter-parent to do the dependency version management responsibility. Here is the **pom.xml** file.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Here is the Kafka consumer code,

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaEventListener {

    @RetryableTopic(
            attempts = "#{'${kafka.max.retry.attempts}'}",
            autoCreateTopics = "#{'${kafka.auto.create.retry.topics}'}",
            backoff = @Backoff(
                    delayExpression = "#{'${kafka.retry.init-interval}'}",
                    multiplierExpression = "#{'${kafka.retry.backoff.multiplier}'}"),
            include = { Exception.class },
            timeout = "#{'${kafka.max.retry.duration}'}",
            topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE,
            dltStrategy = DltStrategy.FAIL_ON_ERROR)
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.test}", groupId = "${kafka.group.id.test}",
            containerFactory = "testKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(@Payload MetadataMessage input, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) String offset) {
        System.out.println(input.getValue());
    }

    @DltHandler
    public void deadLetterHandler(@Payload(required = false) MetadataMessage data,
                                  @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Event from topic %s has been dead-lettered. Event data : %s", topic, data.toString()));
    }
}
```

Here is the Kafka configuration class,

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value(value = "${kafka.group.id.test}")
    private String groupId;


    private Map<String, Object> consumerFactoryConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        // Disabled kafka auto acknowledgement to gain more flexibility
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, "20971520");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, "20971520");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, MetadataMessage> metadataConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerFactoryConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
                new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(new JsonDeserializer<>(MetadataMessage.class)));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MetadataMessage> testKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MetadataMessage> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(metadataConsumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Here is the test class,

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = EmbeddedKafkaApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestPropertySource(locations = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092", "port=29092" })
public class EmbeddedKafkaTest {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaEventListener kafkaEventListener;

    @Test
    public void testKafkaEvent() {
        kafkaEventListener.listen(new MetadataMessage("kafka message from test"), "1", mock(Acknowledgment.class));
    }
}
```

With spring-boot-starter-parent version 3.1.10 the test is working. However, when I switch to a newer version of spring-boot-starter-parent, the test fails.

I can see these logs when start the application when I ran the test cases,

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v3.1.10)

2024-03-31T16:37:37.354+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] k.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$     : Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean
2024-03-31T16:37:37.448+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : 
2024-03-31T16:37:37.448+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :   ______                  _                                          
2024-03-31T16:37:37.448+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :  |___  /                 | |                                         
2024-03-31T16:37:37.448+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :     / /    ___     ___   | | __   ___    ___   _ __     ___   _ __   
2024-03-31T16:37:37.448+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :    / /    / _ \   / _ \  | |/ /  / _ \  / _ \ | '_ \   / _ \ | '__|
2024-03-31T16:37:37.448+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :   / /__  | (_) | | (_) | |   <  |  __/ |  __/ | |_) | |  __/ | |    
2024-03-31T16:37:37.448+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :  /_____|  \___/   \___/  |_|\_\  \___|  \___| | .__/   \___| |_|
2024-03-31T16:37:37.448+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :                                               | |                     
2024-03-31T16:37:37.448+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :                                               |_|                     
2024-03-31T16:37:37.448+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : 
2024-03-31T16:37:37.460+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.6.4--d65253dcf68e9097c6e95a126463fd5fdeb4521c, built on 12/18/2022 18:10 GMT
2024-03-31T16:37:37.460+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Server environment:host.name=SADEEP-M.Zone24x7.lk
2024-03-31T16:37:37.460+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Server environment:java.version=17.0.8.1
2024-03-31T16:37:37.460+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Server environment:java.vendor=Amazon.com Inc.
```

Final log lines of success execution with 3.1.10 version,

```
2024-03-31T16:37:41.551+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [ner#0-dlt-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : testGroupId-dlt: partitions assigned: [testTopic-dlt-0]
2024-03-31T16:37:41.551+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [0-retry-1-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : testGroupId-retry-1: partitions assigned: [testTopic-retry-1-0]
2024-03-31T16:37:41.551+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : testGroupId: partitions assigned: [testTopic-0]
2024-03-31T16:37:41.551+05:30  INFO 26280 --- [0-retry-0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : testGroupId-retry-0: partitions assigned: [testTopic-retry-0-0]
kafka message from test
```

I can see the ZooKeeperServer is running clearly.

But after I changed to the newer version such as 3.2.0 or any latest versions (3.2.4). I cannot see that ZooKeeperServer logs and test also is falling to execute. Here are some logs from that,

```
2024-03-31T16:46:29.072+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.6.1
2024-03-31T16:46:29.072+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 5e3c2b738d253ff5
2024-03-31T16:46:29.072+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1711883789072
2024-03-31T16:46:29.075+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [| adminclient-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-03-31T16:46:29.075+05:30  WARN 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [| adminclient-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2024-03-31T16:46:29.191+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [| adminclient-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-03-31T16:46:29.191+05:30  WARN 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [| adminclient-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2024-03-31T16:46:29.300+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [| adminclient-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-03-31T16:46:29.300+05:30  WARN 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [| adminclient-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2024-03-31T16:46:29.518+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [| adminclient-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Node -1 disconnected.
```

That Zookeeper logs are also not visible,

```
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.4)

2024-03-31T16:46:26.369+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [           main] k.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$     : Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean
2024-03-31T16:46:26.387+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [           main] org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util     : Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation
2024-03-31T16:46:26.501+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-1] kafka.server.ControllerServer            : Formatting C:\Users\sandeepm\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-16755125128047995461\controller_0 with metadata.version 3.3-IV0.
2024-03-31T16:46:26.503+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-3] kafka.server.BrokerServer                : [BrokerServer id=0] Transition from SHUTDOWN to STARTING
2024-03-31T16:46:26.503+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-2] kafka.server.ControllerServer            : [ControllerServer id=0] Starting controller
2024-03-31T16:46:26.504+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-3] kafka.server.SharedServer                : [SharedServer id=0] Starting SharedServer
2024-03-31T16:46:26.524+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-2] o.a.k.s.network.EndpointReadyFutures     : authorizerStart completed for endpoint CONTROLLER. Endpoint is now READY.
2024-03-31T16:46:26.596+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-3] kafka.log.UnifiedLog$                    : [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=C:\Users\sandeepm\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-16755125128047995461\controller_0] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2
2024-03-31T16:46:26.597+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-3] kafka.log.UnifiedLog$                    : [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=C:\Users\sandeepm\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-16755125128047995461\controller_0] Reloading from producer snapshot and rebuilding producer state from offset 0
2024-03-31T16:46:26.597+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-3] kafka.log.UnifiedLog$                    : [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=C:\Users\sandeepm\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-16755125128047995461\controller_0] Producer state recovery took 0ms for snapshot load and 0ms for segment recovery from offset 0
2024-03-31T16:46:26.634+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-3] kafka.raft.KafkaMetadataLog$             : Initialized snapshots with IDs SortedSet() from C:\Users\sandeepm\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-16755125128047995461\controller_0\__cluster_metadata-0
2024-03-31T16:46:26.671+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [piration-reaper] ExpirationService$ExpiredOperationReaper : [raft-expiration-reaper]: Starting
2024-03-31T16:46:26.716+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-3] org.apache.kafka.raft.QuorumState        : [RaftManager id=0] Completed transition to Unattached(epoch=0, voters=[0], electionTimeoutMs=1955) from null
2024-03-31T16:46:26.722+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-3] org.apache.kafka.raft.QuorumState        : [RaftManager id=0] Completed transition to CandidateState(localId=0, epoch=1, retries=1, voteStates={0=GRANTED}, highWatermark=Optional.empty, electionTimeoutMs=1252) from Unattached(epoch=0, voters=[0], electionTimeoutMs=1955)
2024-03-31T16:46:26.727+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-3] org.apache.kafka.raft.QuorumState        : [RaftManager id=0] Completed transition to Leader(localId=0, epoch=1, epochStartOffset=0, highWatermark=Optional.empty, voterStates={0=ReplicaState(nodeId=0, endOffset=Optional.empty, lastFetchTimestamp=-1, lastCaughtUpTimestamp=-1, hasAcknowledgedLeader=true)}) from CandidateState(localId=0, epoch=1, retries=1, voteStates={0=GRANTED}, highWatermark=Optional.empty, electionTimeoutMs=1252)
2024-03-31T16:46:26.800+05:30  INFO 25024 --- [embedded-kafka] [-kit-executor-2] kafka.network.ConnectionQuotas           : Updated connection-accept-rate max connection creation rate to 2147483647
```

I'm having trouble with the dependency version and need some assistance. I want to run all my test cases using an embedded Kafka broker without using an external Kafka cluster. Could you please help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: You've got a lot of complexity going on in your problem explanation. And if that is indicative of the rest of the code base, the problem may not be in the code you've shown here. So you may want to create a new application from scratch and apply the tutorial. If that works, you can start to bridge the gap between your setup and your now working demo. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/testing.html

Comment: You can also put some breakpoints in `GlobalEmbeddedKafkaTestExecutionListener` and see what is happening.